# Can I change an image on jquery hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, jquery-hover

I have this big image displaying and on the bottom I have small images, I want the big image to the image I am hovering over if possible. Thanks.
This is the code I have.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="img/1.png" alt="image 1">
    </div>
    <ul class="small">
        <li> <img src="img/1.png" alt="image 2"> </li>
        <li> <img src="img/2.png" alt="image 2"> </li>
        <li> <img src="img/3.png" alt="image 2"> </li>
        <li> <img src="img/4.png" alt="image 2"> </li>
        <li> <img src="img/5.png" alt="image 2"> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery but doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.small').hover(function() {
            $('.inner img').attr('src' = '.small img src')
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.small img').hover(function () {
        $('.inner img').attr('src' ,this.src)
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kt6tn/)

Comment: This is better +1, you dont need to use `$(this).attr('src')`

Answer (score 0):

```
.attr("src", "small img src");
```

The above is the JavaScript syntax for passing arguments to methods.  `'string' = 'string'` is not valid JavaScript syntax at all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$('.inner img').attr('src' = '.small img src');
```

with:

```
$('.inner img').attr('src' = $(this).attr('src'));
```

The problem is, `.small img src` doesn't return the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.small li').hover(function () {
        var tmpUrl = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
        $(".inner img").attr("src", tmpUrl);
    });
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a small bug in your logic,

Try rewriting your script as,

```
$('ul.small img').hover(function ()
{
  $('.inner img').attr('src' ,$(this).attr('src'));
});
```